# Как сделать чтобы элемент с position absolute не смещался внутри блока с overflow-x: scroll?

Tags: css

Если проскролить блок вправо, то при наведении на .slide элемент .wrapper смещается вправо. Как сделать, чтобы он оставался на месте родителя .slide?
Знаю, что можно для .slide сделать position: relative но тогда при наведении элемент .bottom будет перекрываться прокруткой, а мне нужно чтобы он был поверх элемента .banner

Разметка:

```css
.products,
.slider-box,
.slider,
.top,
.slide:hover .bottom,
.banner {
  display: flex;
}
.content,
.products {
  width: 600px;
}
.bottom {
  display: none;
}
.products {
  position: relative;
}
.slider-box {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.slide {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slide:hover .wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}
.top {
  height: 80px;
  background: gold;
}
.top,
.bottom,
.banner {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.bottom {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
.banner {
  height: 150px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="products">
    <div class="slider-box">
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="top">
              TOP
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
              BOTTOM
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="top">
              TOP
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
              BOTTOM
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="top">
              TOP
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
              BOTTOM
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="top">
              TOP
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
              BOTTOM
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="top">
              TOP
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
              BOTTOM
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <a href="#">
      LINK LINK LINK LINK LINK LINK LINK LINK LINK
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[На codepen](https://codepen.io/rootsuperuser/pen/QWMzjGz)

Comment: Когда элементу  задаешь `position : absolite ;`,  у родителя должно быть `position : relative ;`, это во-первых, во-вторых не понятно, что именно ты хочешь реализовать в конечном итоге.

Comment: .slide:hover .wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

Comment: @Air хочу чтобы при наведении на .wrapper элемент .bottom показывался проверх полосы прокрутки и элемента .banner но при этом оставить возможность скроллить .slider-box вправо/влево
Если я добавлю его родителю relative .bottom не будет показан поверх .banner

Comment: @Rudi не помогло.

Comment: @DenKuzmin margin-left: 0px; вставь в .slide:hover .wrapper{....} всё работает в твоём же примере на codepen

Comment: @Rudi надо чтобы при наведении .wrapper остался на том же месте, что и без наведения, если .slider-box проскроллен. Сделал как Вы написали. Не сработало. https://ibb.co/qnMWmbR

Comment: Ну возьми элемент bottom сунь в элемент  top

Comment: @Air и что получится? Тоже самое что сейчас во .wrapper